# Asking ls to only list files in a path that match a specific glob/regex

Tags: files, zsh, ls, regular-expression, glob

In Zsh: Is there a way to use `ls` to **only** list files and folders in the **current directory** that match a specific **globbing** or **regex** pattern?

For example, say I have multiple files that start with the character `#`, the following command does **not** do what I want:

```
ls -l #*
```

I know I can do this with find, i.e. `find . "#*" -maxdepth 1 -print`, but I am looking for a solution that lists files and folders with permissions in `ls`.

I presume that one way of doing this is by parsing the output of ls (but AFAIK [this is usually not recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `-d` option to `ls`.

```
ls -ld \#*
```

Comment: Thanks, and I guess and I was also missing the escaping character `\`!